# std::out_of_range despues de un vector de vectores c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un Problema con este vector, el Vector SIGS2 es un vector de vectores pero no entiendo el porque no puedo pasarlo a un vector no se en donde podría estar el error

```
    vector<vector<int>> SIGS2;

    SIGS2 = get_spectral_signature(IMGS);
    print_signatures(SIGS2);
    qDebug()<<"SIGS2";
    qDebug()<<SIGS2.size();
//Error desde aqui

    vector <int> SIGS{SIGS2.at(0).at(0),SIGS2.at(0).at(1),SIGS2.at(0).at(2),SIGS2.at(0).at(3),SIGS2.at(0).at(4),SIGS2.at(0).at(5),SIGS2.at(0).at(6) };
    qDebug()<<SIGS;
```

Este es el output que da el programa cuando pasa por ese tramo del codigo

```
OutPut: Firma-0
51,
244,
197,
69,
244,
136,
244,

SIGS2
std::vector(std::vector(51, 244, 197, 69, 244, 136, 244))
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 7) >= this->size() (which is 7)
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/pi/Desktop/build-Sipova-Desktop-Release/untitled2 crashed.
```

He visto el error que manda pero aun no he podido encontrar solución a esto, Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que comentas sucede porque intentas acceder al 8º elemento de un vector, por ejemplo con

```
SIGS2.at(0).at(7)
```

o con

```
SIGS.at(7)
```

Cuando el tamaño de ese vector es 7.

Este error sería posterior a la ejecución del código que adjuntas